# How fast can a file be written/read

Tags: c, microcontroller

I was given a task to build a sinusoidal generator using some microcontroller programmed in C (using PSIM). So in my function I'm calculating needed values and store them in a [25] array. Function receives current time from some element, and according to the time I need to select proper element from the array. I could not think about different way of getting the position of element than reading it from a file and then rewriting with a new one. But is the system able to perform this operation 5000 times per second ?

Function calculating arrays :

```
int main(){
    double amp = 128;                             
    float norm[25];
    float s;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i< 25; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            norm[i] = 0;
        }
        norm[i] = i*2*M_PI/100;
        s = amp*sin(norm[i]);
        norm[i] = s;
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Template of main function in the controller :

```
__declspec(dllexport)opc1(double t, double dt, double *in, double *out){
    double u = in[0];
    //this value should be read from the array according to the counter position
    out[0] = y;
}
```

Comment: We cannot tell you that without knowing anything about the µC you are using.

Comment: just thought about different way. I should have the previous value available so I can take element coming next after this value in my array. But still I need to get the phase from the file so question remains.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to store a value in the file.  Does the value need to persist between program runs?  If not, why aren't you just using a variable in your program?

Comment: currently it's a hypothetical microcontroller only :/

Comment: because this declspec function is run each time I'm generating a value so I cannot store any values in it.

Comment: Could you show where you'd be reading / writing to the file in your code sample?

Comment: I am confused. You need to write a sinusoid generator, and your norm[] array has a sinus wave (rough as it is) in it. What are you reading from a file, and why?

Comment: Read up on global and static data.

Answer (score 1):

Can't understand the need for using a file. Having a microcontroller perform 5,000 `open()`, `read()` and `close()` operations (or the equivalent) per second seems like a very tough requirement. Assuming it runs at 20 MHz, that's gives 4,000 cycles to perform all the operations.

Probably not impossible, if one imposes some **very** strict limits, but unlikely. Especially considering that that count includes the work done by any device drivers for the disk (or whatever media holds the file).

If the code is not loaded/unloaded between every call, why not just use `static` variable(s) to store the state?